# Standard method or best practices for foreign keys when exporting and merging databases

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a best practice when merging two databases (with identical schema) that have tables with foreign keys? I'm looking for a way with MySQL (or any standard SQL language feature) to export the rows with a place holder for the foreign key and, upon import, insert the proper newly assigned value once the row which defines the foreign key (via auto-increment) has assigned one.

I can do this via programming outside of SQL but am curious if there is a better approach using only SQL or MySQL-specific methods.

If programming is the only option, is there a recommended method (export as JSON)? My attempts work but are not elegant and I end up writing all the import methods myself which is prone to errors and bugs.

Comment: I can't get beyond the first sentence.  Why would two *identical* databases need to be merged?

Comment: Other considerations aside, this is a good use case for using natural keys instead of synthetic keys.  If you're going to be doing this operation repeatedly, consider re-keying the databases.

Comment: @rd_nielsen - see my answer. That's pretty much the only usable method I am aware of

Comment: @GordonLinoff - as near as I can parse it, they are two databases with identical table structures, where the foreign key on one table happens to be identity column on another table (which means you can't just easily merge the data)

Comment: Yes, I meant to say "two databases with identical schema". My apologies.

Comment: clarified the question (in regard to two databases with identical schema) for any future reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any native methods, but my general approach when dealing with such situations (if I understand your question correctly - clone data that would have 2 tables, joined by a foreign key for a second table that happens to be an identity column on first table), is as follows:

NOTE: this ONLY works if the first table (the one with identity column that serves as a foreign key, ALSO has a unique set of columns that is not the identity column). This is called a "[**natural key**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key)" (hat/tip @rd_nielsen). Hopefully, you already have one in the form of a unique index on first table that isn't the unique key.

Example: Table "t1" has columns `id1, c1, c2, c3, c4` and table "t2" has `id2, id1, d1, d2, d3` where id1 is an identity column in t1 and a foreign key in t2; and c1+c2 is a natural key in t1.

The technique relies on building a temporary transition table that replaces the foreign key in second table to be first table's natural key, instead of first table's identity column.

1. Find unique combo of columns (`c1+c2` in this example) in first table which is the natural key.
2. Run a join query, that joins first table's natural key's columns, with the second table; via the foreign key; into a temp table.

   ```
   -- Sybase syntax.
   SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.d1, t2.d2, t2.d3
   INTO   tempdb..t2_lookupable
   WHERE  t1.id1 = t2.id1

   -- While at it, let's build the migratable columns (everything except identity) for t1
   SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t1.c4
   INTO   tempdb..t1_lookupable
   ```
3. Clone the data from tempdb..t1_lookupable and tempdb..t2_lookupable tables to the target as needed.

   **This can involve doing merges between your two databases worth of data**, or anything else that is needed to be done. Could be bcp out/in, could be some other method - depends on what you do.
4. Populate new t1 table from data in tempdb..t1_lookupable on target

   ```
   -- Could be a BCP
   SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4   -- id1 will get autopopulated, being an identity column
   FROM   tempdb..t1_lookupable
   ```
5. Now, the tricky part - populate the new t2 table, from a combo of new t1 table, and t2_lookupable table, by finding correct new "id1" value by joining those 2 tables on c1, c2 unique key set:

   ```
   SELECT t1.id1, t2t.d1, t2t.d2, t2t.d3
   INTO   
   FROM   t1, tempdb..t2_lookupable t2t
   WHERE  t1.c1 = t2t.c1
    AND   t1.c1 = t2t.c2
   ```

Comment: If the tables all have natural keys, then the tables from the second database can be imported into staging tables in the first database, then upsert operations run to merge each staging table into its corresponding base table.  In case of identical primary keys, it will be necessary to decide whether or not attribute columns from the staging tables overwrite the corresponding data in the base tables.  Because MySQL supports the information schema, these upserts can be automated so that they are driven by information on keys and columns in the information schema.